# Magento Shopping Cart Rules discount + Tier Price

Tags: magento

Is the following scenario possible in Magento?.

Tiering pricing and bulk discount will be applicable to the same order.
I want 4% discount on total over $200.
However the tiering priced product price will not be considered toward bulk discount Rule.

e.g I have 4 product

```
product 1 price = 10  and having tier price = $8 for 5+ products
product 2 price = 10
product 3 price = 100
product 4 price = 140
```

so if i order like

```
product 1 qty-6  price = $48
priduct 2 qty-1  price = 10
priduct 3 qty-1  price = 100
priduct 4 qty-1  price = 140
```

we apply tier pricing for Product 1, which will not be eligible for bulk pricing.
However the remaining amount will still be eligible for bulk pricing. 
This means, 4%  discount will be applied to $250 (10 + 100 + 140).

I need to substract the product total which has tier price applied in the cart and need to check the remaining product total against my shopping cart rules for discount.

can any one please guide me how do i achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to create it and it doesn't work or what ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function calculatePrice($basePrice, $specialPrice, $specialPriceFrom, $specialPriceTo,
            $rulePrice = false, $wId = null, $gId = null, $productId = null)
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start('__PRODUCT_CALCULATE_PRICE__');
        if ($wId instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Store) {
            $sId = $wId->getId();
            $wId = $wId->getWebsiteId();
        } else {
            $sId = Mage::app()->getWebsite($wId)->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStoreId();
        }

        $finalPrice = $basePrice;
        if ($gId instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Group) {
            $gId = $gId->getId();
        }

        $finalPrice = self::calculateSpecialPrice($finalPrice, $specialPrice,          $specialPriceFrom, $specialPriceTo, $sId);

        if ($rulePrice === false) {
            $storeTimestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($sId);
            $rulePrice = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')
                ->getRulePrice($storeTimestamp, $wId, $gId, $productId);
        }

        if ($rulePrice !== null && $rulePrice !== false) {
            $finalPrice = min($finalPrice, $rulePrice);
        }

        $finalPrice = max($finalPrice, 0);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('__PRODUCT_CALCULATE_PRICE__');
        return $finalPrice;
    }
```

in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price has

```
 if ($rulePrice === false) {
            $storeTimestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($sId);
            $rulePrice = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')
                ->getRulePrice($storeTimestamp, $wId, $gId, $productId);
        }
```

So within $rulePrice == false check for qty of product and whether any bulk pricing applicable if yes then

```
if ($rulePrice === false) {
            $storeTimestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($sId);
            $flag = $this->someCheckFunction()  // This function you will have to write
            if($flag == 1) {

            $rulePrice = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')
                ->getRulePrice($storeTimestamp, $wId, $gId, $productId);
           }
        }
```

Comment: I will try and check it asap Thanks

Comment: i think the above code is for Catalog Rules and it may not work for my requirement.I have added the sales rule with "Percent of Product Price discount".